# Howto include template code by condition in jade?

Tags: javascript, meteor, pug, meteor-blaze

Hi i am using Meteor with some jade (blaze) templates:

```
template(name="userFormsLayout")
  section.auth-layout
    section.auth-dialog
     +samlLogin
     //+Template.dynamic(template=content)
```

i would like to include the commented section by a condition:

```
template(name="userFormsLayout")
  section.auth-layout
    section.auth-dialog
     +samlLogin
     var cond = true
     if(cond)
       +Template.dynamic(template=content)
```

I also have this javascript for this template

```
Template.userFormsLayout.helpers({
  languages() {
    return _.map(TAPi18n.getLanguages(), (lang, tag) => {
      const name = lang.name;
      return { tag, name };
    });
  },

  isCurrentLanguage() {
    const t9nTag = i18nTagToT9n(this.tag);
    const curLang = T9n.getLanguage() || 'en';
  return t9nTag === curLang;
  },
});
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you setting the var ```cond``` in your actual template?

Comment: see update, it looks exactly like this, ok i tried some different versions with brackets... but ended always up with errors

Comment: Where is the value of ```cond``` coming from?

Comment: Nowhere, i just hacked it in the jade file. `var cond = true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Meteor way to do this would be to set the variable `cond` in a helper. Example:

Helper:

```
Template.userFormsLayout.helpers({
  cond() {
    // a function that returns 'true' or 'false'
    return true;
  },
});
```

Template:

```
template(name="userFormsLayout")
  section.auth-layout
    section.auth-dialog
     +samlLogin
     if(cond)
       +Template.dynamic(template=content)
```

Comment: Can you also return self defined objects this way?

Comment: Yes, if you returned ```{ name: 'test', value: true }``` then in your template you could use ```{{cond.name}}``` or ```{{cond.value}}```